# $http.post() freezing chrome browser after file upload the file for import

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, http, file-upload

I am stuck, where is the memory leakages?

**What I am trying?**

After import the .xlsx (store) I am fetching them again in the response (I also try to fetch them independently on other ele click event ).

**Problem:**

After uploading 2 -3 files chrome browser freeze on $http.post(...) ( Working fine in FF), I have added code sample.

Thanks!

```
/***** HTML *****
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().storeBulkUpdate(this)">
*****/

/***  Controller  */
var paginationCriteria = {
    pageNo: 1,
    size: 10
};

$scope.getAllStoreStores = function (_data, qParam) {
    storeSevice.getStore(_data, $httpParamSerializer(qParam)).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
}

$scope.storeBulkUpdate = function (element) {
    var fileData = element.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileData);
    storeSevice.bulkUpdateStore(formData).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.getAllStore({}, paginationCriteria);
    });
};


/**Factory 'storeSevice' */
return {
    bulkUpdateStore: function (_postData) {
        url = '/upload'
        //Set Headers
        var header = {};
        var extendedHeader = AuthenticationService.createAuthorizationHeader(
            header,
            url,
            'POST',
            _postData
        );
        extendedHeader['ServiceName'] = 'uploadMTTForStore';
        extendedHeader['Content-Type'] = undefined;
        //Headers End
        return $http.post(url, _postData, {
            withCredentials: false,
            headers: extendedHeader,
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        });
    },

    getStore: function (_postData, $parameters) {
        url = '/getStore?' + $parameters;
        var header = {};
        var extendedHeader = AuthenticationService.createAuthorizationHeader(
            header,
            url,
            'POST'
        );
        extendedHeader['ServiceName'] = 'storeFetch';

        //browser feerze
        return $http.post(url, $postData, {
            headers: extendedHeader
        });
    },

    otherMethods: "etc......."
}
```